# Checkbox on click get value of radio button

Tags: jquery

All,

I have this set up. Now it needs modifications.

1. When the page first loads, one of the radio button in the is preselected eg. All Met or All Not Met or All Missed. For now all the Met buttons are selected.
2. All the radio buttons are disabled. When the check-box is selected then the row id, value of the radio button checked of that row only should be populated on the text area.(Works partly)
3. When the check-box is unchecked then the value populated when the check-box is checked previously needs to be removed.(Does not work)
4. If the user selects a different radio button (after check-box is selected ) then the value needs to be updated.(Works)
5. Also when Missing radio button is select, a text field shows and the inputted value needs to be updated. (Throws Undefined)

I have done quite a bit but things are not working.

Can gurus help, again it is much appreciated ?

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jj4Uv/35/)

```
$("input:radio").hover(function () {
$(this).prev('.r-title').show();
 }, function () {
if (!$(this).is(':checked')) {
    $(this).siblings('.r-title, .m-notes').hide();
}
 });

//Radio Buttons

$("input:radio").click(function () {
$(this).parent().parent().find('.r-title, .m-notes').hide();
var totalRd = $('table').find('input:radio:checked').length;
var clicked = [];
$("#totalRd .rd-count").html(totalRd); //Counts the radio buttons clicked
$(this).siblings('.r-title, .m-notes').show();
$('table').find("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function () {
var selectedId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
var newVal = ($(this).next('.m-notes:visible').length) ? this.value + "~" +                $(this).next('.m-notes:visible').val() : this.value;
clicked.push(selectedId + "~" + newVal);
 }); //checked
$("#inputhere").val(clicked.join('|'));
});

//Input Field for Missing Radio Button

$('.m-notes').keyup(function () {
var $self = $(this);
var clicked = [];
$('table').find("input[type=radio]:checked").each(function () {
    var selectedId = $(this).parent().parent().attr('id');
    var newVal =  this.value + "~" + $(this).next('.m-notes').val();
    clicked.push(selectedId + "~" + newVal);
}); //checked
$("#inputhere").val(clicked.join('|'));
});

//CheckBox
var clicked=[];
$("input:checkbox").change(function(){
$(this).parent().parent().find("input[type=radio]").prop('disabled',!this.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

With this you get the value of selected radio on check/uncheck checkbox:

```
$("input:checkbox").change(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().find("input[type=radio]").prop('disabled',!this.checked);

    $("#inputhere").val("");
    $(".chkBx").each(function(){
        if($(this).prop("checked")){
            var txtVal = $(this).parents("div").eq(1).find("input[type='radio']:checked").val();
            var idRowVal = $(this).parents("div").eq(1).attr("id");
            var textboxPrevValue = $("#inputhere").val();
            var textAndIdVal = textboxPrevValue + txtVal + " " +  idRowVal + " ";
            $("#inputhere").val(textAndIdVal);
        }
    });

});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jj4Uv/37/)

Comment: I add this on checkbox change function you have. You want it on save button click?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand but when the check box is clicked then only the row id and value of the radio button checked should be populated in the text area. If the check box is unchecked then it should not be in the text area. Hope this helps.

Comment: Alek, getting there. But when the Check box is unchecked, it removes everything, it needs to remove only the row id and value of the radio button of the corresponding checkb box when it is unticked. Did you see my updated fiddle ?

Comment: It doesn't remove everything. Check my fiddle. It removes the unchecked and keeps the checked ones. I think the only change you need to add is my first post `$(this).parents("div").eq(1).find("input[type='radio']:checked").val();`

Comment: Hi! Thanks saw it looks like it is working but when you change the radio buttons from Not Met to Met then it populates all the checked radio button.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add this in your condition

```
$(this).parents("div").eq(1).find("input[type='radio']").val();//add this
```

Comment: no offence but i posted the same answer as you long before :)

Comment: Hi! Sagar, Alek posted this a while ago..please take look at my updated fiddle